# Display vector co-ordinates as String values

Tags: c#, vector, static, xna, draw

I am right now trying to display a vector holding an X and Y value, for a sprite, from one class `Game Object.cs` to `Game1.cs`. I move a protected value (`protected Vector2 velocity;`) to a `public Vector2 velocity` when I move it over the draw method (so that it will show how fast the sprite on screen is moving) it comes up with `Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property`. So I add static, now it's `public static Vector2 velocitys`, and play the game. When I look at the X and Y value, they'er there but will not change when I move. I have had this problem on anything with a static.

Is there a way to get rid of the static, or fix this so I can see the X and Y update while I am playing? I have the `velocitys` Vector take `velocity`'s X and Y in the update in `GameObject.cs` so that it will constantly take from velocity.

Why does it need a static? Can I change that? Can I update it on the screen?

This is the code:

GameObject.cs:

(Holdes the Vectors velocitys and velocity)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Tile_Engine;

namespace **
{
public class GameObject
{
    #region Declarations
    protected Vector2 worldLocation;
    protected Vector2 velocity;
    protected int frameWidth;
    protected int frameHeight;

    protected bool enabled;
    protected bool flipped = false;
    protected bool onGround;

    protected Rectangle collisionRectangle;
    protected int collideWidth;
    protected int collideHeight;
    protected bool codeBasedBlocks = true;

    protected float drawDepth = 0.85f;
    protected Dictionary<string, AnimationStrip> animations =
        new Dictionary<string, AnimationStrip>();
    protected string currentAnimation;

    public Vector2 velocitys;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return enabled; }
        set { enabled = value; }
    }

    public Vector2 WorldLocation
    {
        get { return worldLocation; }
        set { worldLocation = value; }
    }

    public Vector2 WorldCenter
    {
        get
        {
            return new Vector2(
                (int)worldLocation.X + (int)(frameWidth / 2),
                (int)worldLocation.Y + (int)(frameHeight / 2));
        }
    }

    public Rectangle WorldRectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle(
                (int)worldLocation.X,
                (int)worldLocation.Y,
                frameWidth,
                frameHeight);
        }
    }

    public Rectangle CollisionRectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle(
                (int)worldLocation.X + collisionRectangle.X,
                (int)worldLocation.Y + collisionRectangle.Y,
                collisionRectangle.Width,
                collisionRectangle.Height);
        }
        set { collisionRectangle = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Helper Methods
    private void updateAnimation(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (animations.ContainsKey(currentAnimation))
        {
            if (animations[currentAnimation].FinishedPlaying)
            {
                PlayAnimation(animations[currentAnimation].NextAnimation);
            }
            else
            {
                animations[currentAnimation].Update(gameTime);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public void PlayAnimation(string name)
    {
        if (!(name == null) && animations.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            currentAnimation = name;
            animations[name].Play();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (!enabled)
            return;

        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        updateAnimation(gameTime);

        if (velocity.Y != 0)
        {
            velocitys = velocity;
            onGround = false;
        }

        Vector2 moveAmount = velocity * elapsed;

        moveAmount = horizontalCollisionTest(moveAmount);
        moveAmount = verticalCollisionTest(moveAmount);

        Vector2 newPosition = worldLocation + moveAmount;

        newPosition = new Vector2(
            MathHelper.Clamp(newPosition.X, 0,
            Camera.WorldRectangle.Width - frameWidth),
            MathHelper.Clamp(newPosition.Y, 2 * (-TileMap.TileHeight),
            Camera.WorldRectangle.Height - frameHeight));

        worldLocation = newPosition;
    }

    public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if (!enabled)
            return;
        if (animations.ContainsKey(currentAnimation))
        {
            SpriteEffects effect = SpriteEffects.None;

            if (flipped)
            {
                effect = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
            }

            spriteBatch.Draw(
                animations[currentAnimation].Texture,
                Camera.WorldToScreen(WorldRectangle),
                animations[currentAnimation].FrameRectangle,
                Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, effect, drawDepth);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Map-Based Collision Detecting Methods
    private Vector2 horizontalCollisionTest(Vector2 moveAmount)
    {
        if (moveAmount.X == 0)
            return moveAmount;

        Rectangle afterMoveRect = CollisionRectangle;
        afterMoveRect.Offset((int)moveAmount.X, 0);
        Vector2 corner1, corner2;

        if (moveAmount.X < 0)
        {
            corner1 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Left,
                afterMoveRect.Top + 1);
            corner2 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Left,
                afterMoveRect.Bottom - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            corner1 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Right,
                afterMoveRect.Top + 1);
            corner2 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Right,
                afterMoveRect.Bottom - 1);
        }

        Vector2 mapCell1 = TileMap.GetCellByPixel(corner1);
        Vector2 mapCell2 = TileMap.GetCellByPixel(corner2);

        if (!TileMap.CellIsPassable(mapCell1) ||
            !TileMap.CellIsPassable(mapCell2))
        {
            moveAmount.X = 0;
            velocity.X = 0;
        }

        if (codeBasedBlocks)
        {
            if (TileMap.CellCodeValue(mapCell1) == "BLOCK" ||
                TileMap.CellCodeValue(mapCell2) == "BLOCK")
            {
                moveAmount.X = 0;
                velocity.X = 0;
            }
        }
        return moveAmount;
    }

    private Vector2 verticalCollisionTest(Vector2 moveAmount)
    {
        if (moveAmount.Y == 0)
            return moveAmount;

        Rectangle afterMoveRect = CollisionRectangle;
        afterMoveRect.Offset((int)moveAmount.X, (int)moveAmount.Y);
        Vector2 corner1, corner2;

        if (moveAmount.Y < 0)
        {
            corner1 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Left + 1,
                afterMoveRect.Top);
            corner2 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Right - 1,
                afterMoveRect.Top);
        }
        else
        {
            corner1 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Left + 1,
                afterMoveRect.Bottom);
            corner2 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Right - 1,
                afterMoveRect.Bottom);
        }
        Vector2 mapCell1 = TileMap.GetCellByPixel(corner1);
        Vector2 mapCell2 = TileMap.GetCellByPixel(corner2);

        if (!TileMap.CellIsPassable(mapCell1) ||
            !TileMap.CellIsPassable(mapCell2))
        {
            if (moveAmount.Y > 0)
                onGround = true;
            moveAmount.Y = 0;
            velocity.Y = 0;
        }

        if (codeBasedBlocks)
        {
            if (TileMap.CellCodeValue(mapCell1) == "BLOCK" ||
                TileMap.CellCodeValue(mapCell2) == "BLOCK")
            {
                if (moveAmount.Y > 0)
                    onGround = true;
                moveAmount.Y = 0;
                velocity.Y = 0;
            }
        }
        return moveAmount;
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Game1.cs:

(Draws the Vector2 velocity)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Tile_Engine;

namespace **
{
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Player player;

    SpriteFont pericles8;
    Vector2 scorePosition = new Vector2(20, 580);

    enum GameState { TitleScreen, Playing, PlayerDead, GameOver };
    GameState gameState = GameState.TitleScreen;

    Vector2 gameOverPosition = new Vector2(350, 300);
    Vector2 livesPosition = new Vector2(600, 580);
    Vector2 Velocitys = new Vector2(100, 580);

    Texture2D titleScreen;

    float deathTimer = 0.0f;
    float deathDelay = 5.0f;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        this.graphics.ApplyChanges();

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        TileMap.Initialize(
            Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\PlatformTiles"));
        TileMap.spriteFont =
            Content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"Fonts\Pericles8");

        pericles8 = Content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"Fonts\Pericles8");
        titleScreen = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\TitleScreen");

        Camera.WorldRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 160 * 48, 12 * 48);
        Camera.Position = Vector2.Zero;
        Camera.ViewPortWidth = 800;
        Camera.ViewPortHeight = 600;

        player = new Player(Content);
        LevelManager.Initialize(Content, player);
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        GamePadState gamepadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        if (gameState == GameState.TitleScreen)
        {
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) ||
                gamepadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                StartNewGame();
                gameState = GameState.Playing;
            }
        }

        if (gameState == GameState.Playing)
        {
            player.Update(gameTime);
            LevelManager.Update(gameTime);
            if (player.Dead)
            {
                if (player.LivesRemaining > 0)
                {
                    gameState = GameState.PlayerDead;
                    deathTimer = 0.0f;
                }
                else{
                    gameState = GameState.GameOver;
                    deathTimer = 0.0f;
                }
            }
        }

        if (gameState == GameState.PlayerDead)
        {
            player.Update(gameTime);
            LevelManager.Update(gameTime);
            deathTimer = elapsed;
            if (deathTimer > deathDelay)
            {
                player.WorldLocation = Vector2.Zero;
                LevelManager.ReloadLevel();
                player.Revive();
                gameState = GameState.Playing;
            }
        }
        if (gameState == GameState.GameOver)
        {
            deathTimer += elapsed;
            if (deathTimer > deathDelay)
            {
                gameState = GameState.TitleScreen;
            }
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        spriteBatch.Begin(
            SpriteSortMode.BackToFront,
            BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        if (gameState == GameState.TitleScreen)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(titleScreen, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        }
        if ((gameState == GameState.Playing) ||
            (gameState == GameState.PlayerDead) ||
            (gameState == GameState.GameOver))
        {
            TileMap.Draw(spriteBatch);
            player.Draw(spriteBatch);
            LevelManager.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                pericles8,
                "Score: " + player.Score.ToString(),
                scorePosition,
                Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                pericles8,
                "Lives Remaining: " + player.LivesRemaining.ToString(),
            livesPosition,
            Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                pericles8,
                "Velocity: " + GameObject.velocitys.ToString(),
                Velocitys,
                Color.White);
        }

        if (gameState == GameState.PlayerDead)
        {
        }
        if (gameState == GameState.GameOver)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                pericles8,
                "G A M E  O V E R !",
                gameOverPosition,
                Color.White);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    private void StartNewGame()
    {
        player.Revive();
        player.LivesRemaining = 3;
        player.WorldLocation = Vector2.Zero;
        LevelManager.LoadLevel(0);
    }
}
}
```

Player.cs:

(A part of the velocity)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Tile_Engine;

namespace **
{
public class Player : GameObject
{
    #region Declarations
    private Vector2 fallSpeed = new Vector2(0, 20);
    private float moveScale = 180.0f;
    private bool dead = false;

    public int score = 0;
    private int livesRemaining = 3;
    #endregion

    public bool Dead
    {
        get { return dead; }
    }

    public int Score
    {
        get { return score; }
        set { score = value; }
    }

    public int LivesRemaining
    {
        get { return livesRemaining; }
        set { livesRemaining = value; }
    }

    public void Kill()
    {
        PlayAnimation("die");
        LivesRemaining--;
        velocity.X = 0;
        dead = true;
    }

    public void Revive()
    {
        PlayAnimation("idle");
        dead = false;
    }

    #region Constructor
    public Player(ContentManager content)
    {
        animations.Add("idle",
            new AnimationStrip(
                content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\Sprites\Player\Idle"),
                48,
                "idle"));
        animations["idle"].LoopAnimation = true;

        animations.Add("run",
            new AnimationStrip(
                content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\Sprites\Player\Run"),
                48,
                "run"));
        animations["run"].LoopAnimation = true;

        animations.Add("jump",
            new AnimationStrip(
                content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\Sprites\Player\Jump"),
                48,
                "jump"));
        animations["jump"].LoopAnimation = false;
        animations["jump"].FrameLength = 0.08f;
        animations["jump"].NextAnimation = "idle";

        animations.Add("die",
            new AnimationStrip(
                content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\Sprites\Player\Die"),
                48,
                "die"));
        animations["die"].LoopAnimation = false;

        frameWidth = 48;
        frameHeight = 48;
        CollisionRectangle = new Rectangle(9, 1, 30, 46);

        drawDepth = 0.825f;

        enabled = true;
        codeBasedBlocks = false;
        PlayAnimation("idle");
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (!Dead)
        {
            string newAnimation = "idle";

            velocity = new Vector2(0, velocity.Y);
            GamePadState gamePad = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
            KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) ||
                (gamePad.ThumbSticks.Left.X < -0.3f))
            {
                flipped = false;
                newAnimation = "run";
                velocity = new Vector2(-moveScale, velocity.Y);
            }

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) ||
                (gamePad.ThumbSticks.Left.X > 0.3f))
            {
                flipped = true;
                newAnimation = "run";
                velocity = new Vector2(moveScale, velocity.Y);
            }

            if (newAnimation != currentAnimation)
            {
                PlayAnimation(newAnimation);
            }

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) ||
                (gamePad.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed))
            {
                if (onGround)
                {
                    Jump();
                    newAnimation = "jump";
                }
            }

            if (currentAnimation == "jump")
                newAnimation = "jump";

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) ||
                gamePad.ThumbSticks.Left.Y > 0.3f)
            {
                checkLevelTransition();
            }
        }

        velocity += fallSpeed;

        repositionCamera();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        velocity.Y = -500;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Helper Methods
    private void repositionCamera()
    {
        int screenLocX = (int)Camera.WorldToScreen(worldLocation).X;

        if (screenLocX > 500)
        {
            Camera.Move(new Vector2(screenLocX - 500, 0));
        }

        if (screenLocX < 200)
        {
            Camera.Move(new Vector2(screenLocX - 200, 0));
        }
    }

    private void checkLevelTransition()
    {
        Vector2 centerCell = TileMap.GetCellByPixel(WorldCenter);
        if (TileMap.CellCodeValue(centerCell).StartsWith("T_"))
        {
            string[] code = TileMap.CellCodeValue(centerCell).Split('_');

            if (code.Length != 4)
                return;
            LevelManager.LoadLevel(int.Parse(code[1]));
            WorldLocation = new Vector2(
                int.Parse(code[2]) * TileMap.TileWidth,
                int.Parse(code[3]) * TileMap.TileHeight);
            LevelManager.RespawnLocation = WorldLocation;

            velocity = Vector2.Zero;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Comment: Could see see some more code? Were you instantiating your first Vector2?

Comment: It sounds like you have gotten yourself into a right mess. You need to show enough code to be able to replicate the problem, but we don't want all your project code.

Comment: I suspect that you shouldn't have made that `static`. What context were you trying to use it in that generated that error? More likely, you just need to specify the right object reference, or do it from inside an instance method (instead of a static method or field initializer).

Comment: Added the code that is needed for the transfer of the vector.

Comment: Tim S. I have and am trying as many things as I can.

Comment: Please, do not post all of your code in a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out for my self, I mostly wanted a quick answer. Just making a public vector does not help, I needed a method to transfer over the Vector:

```
public Vector2 Velocitys
{
    get { return velocity; }
    set { velocity = value; }
}
```

Then just like the `public int Score` method I draw it:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(
                pericles8,
                "Velocity: " + player.Velocitys.ToString(),
                Velocitys,
                Color.White);
```

It works like a charm.

(Its pretty Ironic that the one thing that I asked why I would use it (get and set) would be the answer)